# Only first form data of dynamic fields are submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I know you may think this was already asked. But I already tried those methods. They don't work for me. When I submit the form it only submits the first fields. I can't figure out by myself. I am new to all these. The following may be a big code but I am pretty sure I messed up. Please, Help.

The complete part is:

https://jsfiddle.net/ytk9jfq4/

The part with the array form elements:

```html
<div class="desc" id="wrapmeemployed" style="display:none;"> 
        <div id="wrapcomplete" class="input_fields_wrap">
        <div id="org-details0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization0"  name="organization[]" />
              <label for="organization0" class="">Name of the Organization / Institution</label>
              <b class="form-text text-danger" id="organizationError0"></b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="desig0"  name="desig[]" />
              <label for="desig0" class="">Designation</label>
              <b class="form-text text-danger" id="desigError0"></b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="workplace0"  name="workplace[]" />
              <label for="workplace0" class="">Place of Work</label>
              <b class="form-text text-danger" id="workplaceError0"></b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form amber-textarea active-amber-textarea">
              <textarea class="md-textarea form-control" style="margin-top:20px;"  id="cadd0" name="cadd[]" row="3" cols="80">
</textarea>
              <label style="margin-top:-13px;margin-left:2px;" for="cadd0" class="">Communication Address</label>
              <b class="form-text text-danger" id="caddError0"></b>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="offemail0"  name="offemail[]" />
              <label for="offemail0" class="">Office Email</label>
              <b class="form-text text-danger" id="offemailError0"></b>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="md-form mb-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact0" name="contact[]" />
              <label for="contact0" class="">Office Contact No</label>
              <b class="form-text text-danger" id="contactError0"></b>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
 <button class="add_field_button" style="font-size:15px;padding:5px 12px;border-radius:5px;background-colour:white;border: 2px solid #3C89B5;margin-top:5px;text-align:center;">Add More Fields</button><br>
        <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

The **Add More Fields** button uses the below append function.

```js
$(".input_fields_wrap").append('<div class="organise'+(x-1)+'"><div id="org-details'+(x-1)+'"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="md-form mb-0"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization'+(x-1)+'"  name="organization[]" /><label for="organization'+(x-1)+'" class="">Name of the Organization / Institution</label><b class="form-text text-danger" id="organizationError'+(x-1)+'">H</b></div></div><div class="col-md-12"><div class="md-form mb-0"><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="desig'+(x-1)+'"  name="desig[]" /><label for="desig'+(x-1)+'" class="">Designation</label><b class="form-text text-danger" id="desigError'+(x-1)+'"></b></div></div><div class="col-md-12"><div class="md-form mb-0"><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="workplace'+(x-1)+'"  name="workplace[]" /><label for="workplace'+(x-1)+'" class="">Place of Work</label><b class="form-text text-danger" id="workplaceError'+(x-1)+'"></b></div></div><div class="col-md-12"><div class="md-form amber-textarea active-amber-textarea"><textarea onclick="$(\'textarea\').autoResize();" class="md-textarea form-control" style="margin-top:20px;"  id="cadd'+(x-1)+'" name="cadd[]" row="1" cols="80"></textarea><label style="margin-top:-13px;margin-left:2px;" for="cadd'+(x-1)+'" class="">Communication Address</label><b class="form-text text-danger" id="caddError'+(x-1)+'"></b></div></div><div class="col-md-12"><div class="md-form mb-0"><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="offemail'+(x-1)+'"  name="offemail[]" /><label for="offemail'+(x-1)+'" class="">Office Email</label><b class="form-text text-danger" id="offemailError'+(x-1)+'"></b></div></div><div class="col-md-12"><div class="md-form mb-0"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact'+(x-1)+'" name="contact[]" /><label for="contact'+(x-1)+'" class="">Office Contact No</label><b class="form-text text-danger" id="contactError'+(x-1)+'"></b></div></div></div></div>');
```

Please don't mark this question as asked or off-topic and make it not accepting answers. I really need help in this code. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Comment: @hedgie The x value is incremented each time the form is added. Initially its 0.